# Setting up networking Ubuntu on VirtualBox with Host-Only networking

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

I'm having difficulty getting host-only networking working right on Virtual Box.  My intention is to have all my VMs on 192.168.1.x and my host on 192.168.0.1.  On my guest machine, I am unable to reach the outside network, though I can get to the gateway.

My VirtualBox Host-only network adapter is setup with

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.0.1
IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.254.0
```

I don't think the IPv6 settings are right, but I don't think I'm using IPv6 anywhere, so I don't think that is the issue.

```
IPv6 Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:0800:27ff:fe00:0000
IPv6 Network Mask Length: 64
```

On my VM guest machine, I have configured it with

```
address 192.168.1.1
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.254.0
```

I am certainly no pro with networking, but the setup looks right to me and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: That's what host-only networking _means_. You aren't supposed to be able to reach the network.

Comment: Seriously? I thought host-only meant only the host could reach it.